# What does a buildPython failure mean in Flutter and Chaquopy?

Tags: flutter, gradle, chaquopy

I'm getting a build failure when I try running code from a Flutter Chaquopy tutorial (https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy).  I'm getting the following build failure, but I don't understand what buildPython means, as I can't find it anywhere in the code.

Here is the build failure:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:mergeDebugPythonSources' (type 'DefaultTask').
  - Property 'buildPython' doesn't have a configured value.

    Reason: This property isn't marked as optional and no value has been configured.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Assign a value to 'buildPython'.
      2. Mark property 'buildPython' as optional.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/validation_problems.html#value_not_set for more details about this problem.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 47s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Here is my main build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://chaquo.com/maven" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.chaquo.python:gradle:12.0.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the app build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.chaquo.python'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.untitled4"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

The Flutter code was copied directly from the tutorial, where the buttons were updated from flat buttons to text buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install Python on your build machine. Or if you've already done so, try setting its location with the `buildPython` setting described [here](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#buildpython).

For updates on this issue, see https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/733.